# How to click on an element which is visible after mouse hover over an element within ebay.com using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to learn selenium with java using [ebay.com](http://ebay.com). I found a difficult element to select element after mouse hover. Here is my snippet code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Tennis')]")).click()
```

However above code return error element not interactable

I have add `Thread.sleep(60000)` before `driver.findElement` and still not able to click

here is the window i wanted to click

[image]

Comment: Try a more specific xpath and test that you can click anything. For instance, find an element with an `id` on ebay and see if you are able to click that. If you can, then you know that the problem is with your xpath selector.

Answer (score 1):

Hover to **Sports** menu using `Actions` and when menu opens click to the **Tennis** submenu. To wait for **Tennis** to be clickable use `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

driver.get("https://www.ebay.com");

WebElement sports = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sports"));

actions.moveToElement(sports).perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Tennis"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *Mouse Hover* over the element with text as **Sports** and wait for the `elementToBeClickable()` with text as **Tennis** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
  //options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/");
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Sports")))).perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sports']//following::div[@class='hl-cat-nav__flyout']//span[text()='Other Categories']//following::ul[1]/li/a[normalize-space()='Tennis']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ebay]